# How to generate all combinations from a list of keywords?

Tags: python, combinations

I want to create domain name generator, I have list with keywords like this >

```
mare italia offerte agosto 2013
mare italia 2013 offerte
mare italia villaggi
mare italia last second
mare italia vacanze
mare italia last minute 2012
mare italia offerte agosto 2012
mare italia offerte last minute
mare italia bello
mare italia piu bello
mare italia hotel
mare italia residence
```

I want to create for every line all possible combinations, how can I do this in Python ?

I need output like this :

```
mare italia
mare italia offerte 
mare italia offerte agosto
mare italia offerte agosto 2013
italia offerte agosto 2013
offerte agosto 2013
agosto 2013
2013 agosto
offerte 2013
2013 offerte
offerte italia
... more
```

my start python code is :

```
database = open('keywords.txt', 'r').readlines()
for line in database:
    print line
```

Comment: Have a look at `itertools` functions `combinaisons` and `permutations`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print all distinct lines

```
from itertools import combinations


final=set()

with open('keywords.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        words=line.strip().split()
        for i in range(2,len(words)):
            for j in combinations(words,i):
                final.add(' '.join(j))

print '\n'.join(final)
```

Comment: This may print lines in arbitrary order as sets are unordered.

Comment: @eugeney I doubt the order matters

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

seen = set()  # keep track of printed lines

with open("keywords.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.rstrip().split()

        for i in range(2, len(words)):
            for c in combinations(words, i):
                l = " ".join(c)
                if l not in seen:
                    print(l) 
                    seen.add(l)
```

Comment: why is the last `if` loop reqd if your adding to a set

Comment: @Kaustav: because if a line is in the set, it has already been printed.